# What do we call people with whom we have occasional daily interaction in terms of services?

Tags: single-word-requests, speech

I mean for example people like the hostel caretaker, the cook at the workplace, the taxi driver, the milkman etc.

What can we call all these people? I meant to say that we need to have a good conduct with these kind of people. But how can we refer them?

Comment: Try 'acquaintances': "a person with whom one has been in contact but who is not a close friend" (*Collins English Dictionary*)

Comment: @JEL Hi, I don't think it's a proper word for it. These people need not be the people whom I already knew and so, are not acquaintance. These are the people with whom we interact for getting a service - like taxi driver, people working in restaurants, servants etc. I, once heard a word for it. But I can not recall it now.

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik do you mean specific people? Like Jeff, the milkman who comes every day or just any service personnel? I edited the questions to refine tags. It would be good if you included an example sentence and clarify exactly whom you are talking about.

Comment: Anyone from whom we get services. Eg: customer care or a taxi driver. We may or may not pay to them.

Comment: Yes...I did read a word, but unable to recall it.

Comment: Few sites refer to them as "community helpers" but I could nothing more specific

Comment: Do you mean the sort of people who are often overlooked or just people we see regularly?

Comment: @Helmar - I think you hit on something with your "service personnel."  How about making it an answer?

Comment: They are the hostel caretaker, the cook at the workplace, the taxi driver, and the milkman.  Why do you need to throw them into a single pot?

Answer (score 1):

**Service industry workers.**  Or [service sector](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/service-sector.asp), [tertiary sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_sector_of_the_economy), service economy, etc.  Lots of overlap with [*pink-collar workers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink-collar_worker) though that term is IMO kind of dated (they've come a long way, baby).  If you're a Downton Abbey type, it's *the hired help* or just *the help* and you're not supposed to mingle with them, let alone marry.  If you're a real jerk it's *the little people*.  Lots of denigrating synonyms. :-(

P.S. Who still has a milkman nowadays??

Answer (score 0):

**Proletarian**

This has some connotations of 19<sup>th</sup> and 20<sup>th</sup> Century class conflicts but its definition is as follows:

> A member of the working class or lower class.